# Specific Regex Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I wish to take a string input from the user and extract words or numbers like so:

```
String problem = "I'm lo#o@king t%o ext!r$act a^ll 6 su*bs(tr]i{ngs.";

String[] solve = {"I'm", "looking", "to", "extract", "all", "6", "substrings"};
```

Basically, I want to extract numbers and words with complete disregard to punctuation except apostrophes. I know how to get words and strings but I can't seem to figure out this tricky part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like the below.

```
String s = "I'm lo#o@king t%o ext!r$act a^ll 6 su*bs(tr]i{ngs.";
String parts[] = s.replaceAll("[^\\s\\w']|(?<!\\b)'|'(?!\\b)", "").split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[I'm, looking, to, extract, all, 6, substrings]
```

**Explanation:**

- `[^\\s\\w']` matches any character but not of space or single quote or word character.
- `(?<!\\b)'(?!\\b)` matches the `'` symbol only if it's not preceded and not followed by a word character.
- `replaceAll` function replaces all the matched characters with an empty string.
- Finally we do splitting on the resultant string according to one or more space characters.

Comment: This is just what I need! But is there a simpler pattern?

Comment: Is the 6 considered a word character? I don't see a integer regex.

Comment: yep, it;'s a string. `[^\\w]` matches any character but not of a word character that is A-Z,a-z,0-9,_ . It really needs replacing and then splitting. I think there is no shorter regex than this.

Comment: This is just the same without double slashes. Honestly, I don't understand regex escapes in any language. I know I've seen you around in Python a lot, and I have difficulty differentiating regex as a raw string as opposed to a literal string.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi you need to escape the backslash one more time in java. That's all.

Comment: Why a downvote? What's wrong with the above code and the explanation?

Comment: How would I extend the expression to allow a single trailing apostrophe for slang spelling? How about a single preceding apostrophe for ancient spelling?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi please consider asking it as a new question.

Comment: Please help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199410/trailing-and-preceding-apostrophes) with the new question.