# Trailing and Preceding Apostrophes

Tags: java, regex

I've already asked a similar question before but I'd like to know if there is a regular expression to parse a string such that number and strings are extracted ignoring all punctuation but allowing a single apostrophe for each word whether it at the beginning middle or end.

```
String problem = "'Cause I''m lo#o@kin' t%o ext!r$act a^ll 8 su*bs(tr]i{ngs.";

String[] solve = {"'Cause", "I'm", "lookin'", "to", "extract", "all", "8", "substrings"};
```

Basically, I want to extract numbers and words with complete disregard to punctuation except single apostrophes. I know how to get words and strings but I can't seem to figure out this tricky part.

Notice that `I'm` contains only one apostrophe even with two in between.

Comment: Show us the regex you've used.

Comment: I've been using the one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709754/specific-regex-pattern) suggested by Avinash but it doesn't handle the apostrophes as expected.

Answer (score 1):

A single replaceAll function and a split function would be enough for this.

```
String problem = "'Cause I''m lo#o@kin' t%o ext!r$act a^ll 8 su*bs(tr]i{ngs.";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(problem.replaceAll("(?!')\\p{P}|\\p{S}|(')+","$1").split("\\s+")));
```

**Output:**

```
['Cause, I'm, lookin', to, extract, all, 8, substrings]
```

**OR**

```
String problem = "'Cause I''m lo#o@kin' t%o ext!r$act a^ll 8 su*bs(tr]i{ngs.";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(problem.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s']|(')+","$1").split("\\s+")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a regex that will strip all symbols and punctuation without single apostrophes:

`[\p{S}\p{P}&&[^']]+`

Result: `'Cause I''m lookin' to extract all 8 substrings`

You will then have to replace double single apostrophes with `.replaceAll`, and then split the same way as in the previous answer.

Here is the code:

```
   String s = "I'm lo#o@king t%o ext!r$act a^ll 6 su*bs(tr]i{ngs.";
   String parts[] = s.replaceAll("[\\p{S}\\p{P}&&[^']]+", "").replaceAll("[']{2}", "'").split("\\s+");
   for (int i=0; i<parts.length; i++)
       System.out.println(parts[i]);
```

Result:

```
I'm                                                                                                                                                                 
looking                                                                                                                                                             
to                                                                                                                                                                  
extract                                                                                                                                                             
all                                                                                                                                                                 
6                                                                                                                                                                   
substrings
```